# How to send notifications to specific users in Microsoft Teams (across multiple teams) from an external api

Tags: rest, microsoft-teams

I want to notify (can be activity feed or 1:1 chat) specific users in Microsoft Teams via an external api. The teams can be of different organizations. I looked into the docs as well, but couldn't figure out the solution. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about the proactively notifying user through external API but yes we have something similar Graph API available for Team which can help user to [install bot proactively in their scope and sending proactive notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp), You might need conversation reference to send proactive notification which you can get when conversationUpdate event is fired This can also be done for Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible - it requires you to build a bot to enable pro-active messaging. There are actually a few different approaches and API options for doing this, but I've got a very comprehensive example of one of the approaches, that includes a .Net and a Node.js sample, at https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/teams-dev-samples/tree/add-proactive-messaging-sample/samples/bot-proactive-messaging. There are links at the bottom of the page to various additional readings as well for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried running it, but couldn't grab the conversationId and ServiceUrl in the tab.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did the bot send you the messages it needed to?

Comment: The tab has two fields for conversationId and serviceUrl which are empty, and thus the request fails.

Comment: oh, I see. So you can put in any combination of conversationid + serviceurl that you have, where the bot is installed, but to _get_ them for the first time, go to the "chat" window and it will show them to you in the message the bot sends. You can also say to the bot any time "GetInfo" and it will show them to you again, but it also shows a link in the message "Click here to go to the tab for this app...", and if you do that it will put them into the tab already for you, for testing

Comment: Hi Hilton, I am very new to microsoft teams, and cound not comprehend why it is so challenging to send a simple notification to each specific users. So far I have created a bot, and bot is sending 1:1 message to the user upon users action first, which provides context and required values. But I am not about to figure out how to message the bot to send 1:1 notification to specific user triggered from external api of my app. In your app, if it was an external web app instead of a teams tab, how would you automatically find the required values so that you can send the message to that user?

Comment: Ok, I see what you're missing. Basically, when your bot receives those values (conversation id and serviceurl) you need to *save* them somewhere (like into a database or something like that), so that you can look them up later. See the note I put in the code sample: "You should store the conversationId and serviceUrl in your data store, perhaps using the aadObjectId as a key for the record"

Comment: That way, when you need them later, you can retrieve them.

Comment: Looks like the serviceUrl is same always, can't I just use the same all the time? why should I save it?

Comment: It's -usually- the same across a tenant, but it's not -guaranteed- to be the same even in the same tenant, or even for the same user -over time-, so Microsoft recommends storing it per conversation.

Comment: By the way, if the original answer was of use, please be sure to Mark as Answer or Upvote, so others can see it's useful if they have the same query